# Obtain Contacts Permission before Navigating (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, contacts

### My issue

I am currently writing an application for IOS using Cordova. One of the screens in my application requires permission to access the contacts and allow the user to import their contacts into their local database.

The problem I have is that I do not want to navigate the user to the 'Import Contacts' screen without first obtaining permission to access the contacts. This is is because; there is no point in navigating to the 'Import Contacts' Screen if the application does not have permission to access the user's contacts.

### Potential Solution

Resultantly, I have come up with the following solution to obtain permission to access the users contacts before actually navigating to the next screen 'import contacts':

```
// Attempt to gather the users local contacts
var options             = new ContactFindOptions();
options.multiple        = true;
options.desiredFields   = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id,navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName];
options.hasPhoneNumber  = true;
var fields              = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, function(){
    // Navigate to the 'import contacts' screen
}, function(){
    // Display an error based on the returned error code
    // Once dismissed, take the user to the home page
}, options);
```

As I am very new to Cordova, I am unaware if the above solution has any caveats. Is the above solution the best way to go about this or is there a better solution?

Please note, I am only concerned about IOS for the moment so if there are issues with other OS's then please do not mention them.